# how to send mail with smtp authentication in php

Tags: php, email, smtp

We are using below code mail send successfully but e-mail goes to spam not in inbox

```
$from = "abc@test.in"; 

$to = "xyz@test.in";  

$subject = "Email Test";

$message = "Dear Sir";

$message .= "This is the test mail";

$headers = "From: abc@test.in" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: I don't think this is something with the code. This is related to the spam filter of the receiver's email provider. Even if it can be fixed by changing some code, the code itself is neither right or wrong. Discussion about spam filters does not fit well on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
```

Use these headers instead of you have used. If you found still problem then its mail server problem, that's refine the coming emails and send to inbox or spam respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Use this settings in your `php.ini`

```
SMTP = smtp.example.com
smtp_port = 25
username = example@example.com
password = yourmailpassord
sendmail_from = example@example.com
```